# How do I convert .pvr (PVRTC) files to .png?

Tags: iphone, png, pvrtc

I am an iPhone developer, and I have some PVRTC files, but lost the original source. Now, I'm trying to bring it to the web, and I'd like to convert these into PNG.

How do I do that? I've tried PVRTexTool, but can't figure out the right controls.

Comment: Hmm I would just keep playing the the PVRTexTool and see if you can save it in any sort of format you can open in an image editor I will download it and see what I can do.

Comment: I looked at the command line (gui probably has this too) and you can convert them from pvr to DXT1 DXT3, or DXT5 and im pretty sure some images programs can open them. Expect some quality loss

Comment: Ahh.. figured it out. Thanks for the help Justin.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Within the PVRTexTool GUI, you don't use File -> Save As. click Edit -> Save MIP-level to save as a regular image format (jpg, png, etc).

Comment: This worked for me in PVRTexTool GUI 3.10. I had to unflip the y axis manually afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me. Since this post is old, that might no longer apply for newer versions, such as mine (4.1.3).

For me, I had to use "Save Image" to be able to choose the PNG format. Other options (such as Save, Save As) only let me use PVR, KTX and DDS.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go on PVRView menu button and Open file and chose your file from your folder 
then go on file menu on top and select save as then save its in your format